# What happens to running tasks when IIS recycles

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis, iis-7.5

To help with performance of the clients, I offload the processing of a request onto a task.  This is done because the processing usually takes a bit of time, and I don't want the clients to be waiting for a while just to get the 200 response.  The web service that offloads the work onto a task is always processing posts.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // check for bad requests -- return 400

    // get copy of the context input stream

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ProcessRequest(contextInputStreamCopy);
    });
}

private void ProcessRequest(Stream inputStream)
{
    try
    {
        // process input stream
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // any server error that would normally result in 500 response are not
        // exposed to the clients, the clients are to see 200 when the server 
        // encounters an error
    }
}
```

So my question is what happens to these tasks when IIS recycles, or when the web site is being stopped.

Comment: While it good general question, think if it really applies in your case. Since you don't seem to care about result of the task or any errors in the task why would you care what happens to it on recycle/crash?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He might care about the side-effects having happened. If it's doing something like inserting bulk data into a database you don't want it to disappear or worse, remain half-done. The task might do error-handling that's not displayed in the UI.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I do care about the result of the processing, its the clients that shouldn't care about any errors.  It was my understanding a general try/catch within the body of a task should keep the task from experiencing an exception in most scenarios, so the task becomes fire and forget, it'll complete when it completes.

Comment: @millimoose You are correct the aborting of a task is leaving my data in a bad state.

Comment: I see. Note that question you are interested in is actually "how to implement transactional support for my data if process that I'm running my code in crashes/kills my AppDomain"... I'd recommend to accept answer that explains behavior of IIS on recycle and ask separate question with reasons why you can DB with support of transactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When IIS recycles, it waits for all that threads to finish and exits - up to the timeout value that have on pool. After that time out they kills all running threads and start again.

So you may set a signaling to your threads to stop when the application request to shut down at `globa.asax` using the `Application_End` functions.

Comment: If I added the task to a list as they were created and then in the `Application_End` did a `Task.WaitAll` would that wait till all tasks have finished?  As it does appear I am getting the occasional thread abort and it is leaving data is a bad state.

Comment: @JGinSD Yes that you can do also - I have done the same, and also signaling to stop. But I say you they wait up to the timeout value. You may need to raise and that time out value on the pool if you can.

Comment: Ah, so even if I waited in the `Application_End` its still possible for the timeout to be reached.

Comment: @JGinSD Yes, there is a timeout on how long can wait. `Shutdown time limit (seconds)` on the pool

Comment: Yep, it is already set pretty high, so I may need to rethink our overall strategy, maybe do something like what Cuong Le suggested.

Answer (score 6):

> What happens to running tasks when IIS recycles

It simply takes your running task down accordingly when IIS recycles. If your task takes a bit time, you should think to run your task on separate process. A corrective approach is to use Queue (MSMQ, RabbitMQ...) to store your tasks and use another process to pick your tasks from queue to run. You can use Windows Service or Console Host with scheduler for this.

[More information](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) from Phil Haack:

> When ASP.NET tears down the AppDomain, it will attempt to flush the existing requests and give them time to complete before it takes down the App Domain. ASP.NET and IIS are considerate to code that they know is running, such as code that runs as part of a request.
>
> Problem is, ASP.NET doesn’t know about work done on a background thread spawned using a timer or similar mechanism. It only knows about work associated with a request.