# Inactive Application Pool shut down on a thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, task-parallel-library

In my web service that takes about one hour and half to get its work done I am doing my processing in it in a `Task.Factory.Run()` method and my web service was inside the `default application pool` in `IIS` on the VM machine. After about 30 minutes my WebService stopped working. I went to windows event log and its was default application pool was *shut down after 20 minutes due to inactivity on the worker thread.*
So does that mean this is the reason my WebService also stopped working? And if yes they why does it think it was inactive? Is it because of `Task.Factory.Run()`  ?

Comment: This may shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526983/what-happens-to-running-tasks-when-iis-recycles

Comment: Or this: ["QueueBackgroundWorkItem to reliably schedule and run background processes in ASP.NET"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the reason. The web service was inactive because it didn't receive any requests.

`WebServices` should be a stateless layer for requests and responses, handled by the application pool. If you need to perform long term processing, you should do it in a different process (for example, a windows service you queue work for using WCF inter-process communication).